# Ambiguous call to inherited template method

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, multiple-inheritance, ambiguous

I am working on a simple event system to practice using the stdlib.

I made an `EventEmitter<T>` class which provides `addListener(T)` and `emitEvent(T)`.

There's a `TestEmitter` class that extends `EventEmitter<int>` and `EventEmitter<std::string>`. The `TestEmitter` class has an `emitTestEvent` method that calls either `emitEvent(1337)` or `emitEvent(std::string("test"))`.

In main() an instance of `TestEmitter` is created and two listeners are added for T=int and T=std::string.

I am getting 4 errors that look like this: `reference to ‘emitEvent’ is ambiguous`. Twice on the `emitEvent` calls and twice on the `addListener` calls.

Here's the full output:

```
main.cpp: In member function ‘virtual void TestEmitter::emitTestEvent()’:
main.cpp:42:4: error: reference to ‘emitEvent’ is ambiguous
main.cpp:23:15: error: candidates are: void EventEmitter<T>::emitEvent(T) [with T = std::basic_string<char>]
main.cpp:23:15: error:                 void EventEmitter<T>::emitEvent(T) [with T = int]
main.cpp:45:4: error: reference to ‘emitEvent’ is ambiguous
main.cpp:23:15: error: candidates are: void EventEmitter<T>::emitEvent(T) [with T = std::basic_string<char>]
main.cpp:23:15: error:                 void EventEmitter<T>::emitEvent(T) [with T = int]
main.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
main.cpp:53:10: error: request for member ‘addListener’ is ambiguous
main.cpp:19:15: error: candidates are: void EventEmitter<T>::addListener(EventEmitter<T>::Listener) [with T = std::basic_string<char>; EventEmitter<T>::Listener = std::function<void(std::basic_string<char>)>]
main.cpp:19:15: error:                 void EventEmitter<T>::addListener(EventEmitter<T>::Listener) [with T = int; EventEmitter<T>::Listener = std::function<void(int)>]
main.cpp:57:10: error: request for member ‘addListener’ is ambiguous
main.cpp:19:15: error: candidates are: void EventEmitter<T>::addListener(EventEmitter<T>::Listener) [with T = std::basic_string<char>; EventEmitter<T>::Listener = std::function<void(std::basic_string<char>)>]
main.cpp:19:15: error:                 void EventEmitter<T>::addListener(EventEmitter<T>::Listener) [with T = int; EventEmitter<T>::Listener = std::function<void(int)>]
```

I am quite confused as to why I am getting this error, the compiler (g++) clearly knows what `T` is for either of the calls but it doesn't know which method to call?

I was able to fix the errors on the `emitEvent` calls by prepending them with `EventEmitter<int>::` and `EventEmitter<std::string>` but I am not sure if this is the right way to fix this problem.

Why are the calls to `emitEvent` and `addListener` ambiguous when the compiler knows the type of `T`? How can I fix this?

I hope I provided enough information, if not let me know. Here's the code:

```
#include <list>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
class EventEmitter {
private:
        typedef std::function<void(T)> Listener;

protected:
        std::list<Listener> listeners_;

public:
        EventEmitter() {};
        virtual ~EventEmitter() {};

        virtual void addListener(Listener listener) {
                listeners_.push_back(listener);
        };

        virtual void emitEvent(T event) {
                typename std::list<Listener>::iterator it = listeners_.begin();
                for(; it != listeners_.end(); ++it) {
                        (*it)(event);
                }
        };
};

class TestEmitter : public EventEmitter<int>, public EventEmitter<std::string> {
private:
        int count_;

public:
        TestEmitter() {};
        virtual ~TestEmitter() {};

        virtual void emitTestEvent() {
                count_ = (++count_) % 2;
                if(count_ == 0) {
                        EventEmitter<int>::emitEvent(1337);
                }
                else {
                        EventEmitter<std::string>::emitEvent(std::string("test"));
                }
        };
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
        TestEmitter emitter;

        emitter.addListener([](int event) {
                std::cout << "Hello: " << event << std::endl;
        });

        emitter.addListener([](std::string event) {
                std::cout << "Bye: " << event << std::endl;
        });

        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                emitter.emitTestEvent();
        }

        return 0;
}
```

Thanks :)

Comment: The compiler is unable to figure out which inherited method to call. I don't know the exact details of why, but a workaround is to call `emitter.EventEmitter<int>::addListener([](int event) { /* ... */ });` and `emitter.EventEmitter<std::string>::addListener([](std::string event) { /* ... */ });` instead.

Comment: `count_ = (++count_ ) % 2;` also has undefined behavior because of sequence point rules. Instead use `count_ = (count_ + 1) % 2;`

Comment: @jotik thanks that work around worked :) And I'll look into sequence point rules, I did not know that! Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: A reasonable explanation would be that the compiler looks by name for the corresponding class that has the method. Now, for emitEvent it sees two entries... the overloading part may happen after determining which class the method name belongs to. I don't see, though, why the compiler cannot resolve this itself

Comment: Okay, as it turns out operator overloading is not allowed across scopes and inerhitance does not merge scopes but the superclasses count as particular scopes. And I have updated my answer below, you might use using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your class inherits two different other classes. Now, there are two methods: EventEmitter::emitTestEvent and EventEmitter::emitTestEvent

Which one is supposed to be called? This is not clear in itself.

You can do the following:

```
emitter.EventEmitter<int>::emitEvent(/* ... */);
```

However, you might overthink your design... What should eventEmit do, when the user of your class calls it? Then, design your classes accordingly, such that they offer this behaviour.

Edit:
Another solution can be found by means of `using`, e.g.:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class A
{
public:
    void foo(int) {cout << "A::foo";}
};

class B
{
public:
    void foo(string) {cout << "B::foo";}
};

class C : public A, public B
{
public:
    using A::foo;
    using B::foo;
};

int main() {
    C c;
    c.foo(10);
    c.foo("hi");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The idea I had was that event listeners would be identified by their parameter. So which of the `emitEvent` methods to call would depend on the argument given to it. A call to `emitEvent` with 1 argument of the type `MessageReceivedEvent` would call all the registered listeners for that specific type, if that makes sense. I could just make one `Event` base class and create listeners that check the type of the given event at runtime but I don't want to use `typeid` or `dynamic_cast`. Maybe I am overthinking it... I'll accept this answer since it does solve my problem (thanks to @jotik too).